# Run bash script with sh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, dash-shell

I have bash script and it requires bash.

Another person try to run it with

```
sh script_name.sh
```

And it fails because sh is symbolic link to dash in his distribution.

```
$ ls -la /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Aug 25 16:06 /bin/sh -> dash
```

I have an idea to use wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/sh
bash script_name.sh
```

The goal is to run .sh script by sh with bash in system having symbolic link to dash.

Comment: What if you just do `./script_name.sh`?

Comment: Or get the other user to run with `bash script_name.sh`? - A wrapper will work too. What is your question?

Comment: You should show your script. What you want is to change your script so that it conforms strictly to Posix `sh` standard.

Comment: strange, if `/bin/sh` points to dash so maybe there is no real `/bin/sh` on this system

Comment: It is really huge and has strong dependency on bash (Arrays, functions, etc.).

Comment: make sure (on that others person system) that bash is installed

Comment: Then you should state that `bash` is explicitly required, that the script should be run with `/bin/bash script_name.sh`, and start that script with `#!/bin/bash` ....

Comment: Yes, it is intalled. For example clean Debian installation has symbolic link /bin/sh -> dash. But of course, it has bash.

Comment: @mzet Most systems do not have a separate `/bin/sh` these days. `/bin/sh` is a "virtual" shell, which can be implemented by any shell that supports the POSIX standard.

Comment: Rename your script `script_name.bash` to emphasize that it is not POSIX-compliant. It's not your problem if someone tries to run a script with the wrong interpreter.

Comment: @mzet, what do you mean "no real `/bin/sh`"? dash _is_ a real `/bin/sh`; the only thing `/bin/sh` is required to be is a POSIX-compliant shell; it's allowed to be _any_ POSIX-compliant shell, and dash is one such shell. POSIX.2 has been the controlling standard since the early 90s; it's been many, many decades since there was One True Bourne Shell.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well, usually you use the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) to tell the shell to use the correct interpreter:

```
#!/bin/bash

# your script here
```

You have to set the script to be executable:

```
chmod +x my_script.sh
```

And let the user start it with:

```
./my_script.sh
```

It seems simple than to use a wrapper script.

You can use jbr test to run your script with bash even if the user use sh/dash or any sh like interpreter:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ]
then
    exec bash "$0" "$@"
fi

# Your script here
```

This way it correctly works with either :

```
sh ./my_script.sh

# or

bash ./my_script.sh

# or

./my_script.sh
```

Comment: But that doesn't prevent the user from doing `sh script.sh`.

Comment: @neuro I modified your example to include parameters passed to the script.

Comment: @neuro Yes, you can get rid of it.

Comment: @lemon tree: You're welcome. That was team work. Thanks to jbr and devnull too ^^

Answer (score 4):

In your script before you anything else, you can do something like:

```
if [ "$BASH" != "/bin/bash" ]; then
  echo "Please do ./$0"
  exit 1
fi
```

or the more general way is using `$BASH_VERSION`:

```
if [ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
  echo "Please do ./$0"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I guess that `if [ ! "$BASH" ];` might be a better approach.

Comment: No, because `$BASH` might be `/bin/sh` if bash is used for sh compatibility.

Comment: And what if `bash` was available in `/usr/bin`?

Comment: Then you change the script to `if [ "$BASH" != $( which bash ) ]`, or use `$BASH_VERSION` instead.

Comment: @jbr: with some more code you can run the script with your test