# Ubuntu bash script to run .sh file

Tags: ubuntu, scripting

I have a script that I want to use to start Android Studio easily. Here is the content of the script:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    echo "Script is working"
    /home/user/Desktop/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

I have made it executable using chmod +x, and it runs (I know because it prints the string).

However, it always tells me that the third line contains 'No such file or directory'. When I copy and paste the third line into terminal it works fine, and Optic Studio starts. What am I doing wrong?

I have looked at other answers such as:

[Run bash script with sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538669/run-bash-script-with-sh)
and
[How to run sh file from another sh file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305714/how-to-run-sh-file-from-another-sh-file)

but they haven't helped.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `sh /home/user/Desktop/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`

Comment: @AmanuelNega it shouldn't matter if he can run it directly from the terminal. @cohara, if you run `ls /home/user/` in that third line, do you see what you expect?

Comment: Also, did you mean it says no such file `studio.sh`, or could it be a line inside `studio.sh` throwing the error?

Comment: Thanks Amanuel Nega and kabanus. Amanuel Nega, the problem is not with studio.sh, tht works fine when I run it manually. kabanus, no I don't get what I expect when I run /home/user. Instead I get the error: 'ls: cannot access '/home/user'$'\r': No such file or directory'

Comment: Just to add, commands such as ls and pwd do not work either (command not found). realpath works. My $PATH does contain /home/user/bin

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the executor is not able to find the location.
edit the run.sh file as :-

```
   #!/bin/sh
    echo "Script is working"
    cd /home/user/Desktop/android-studio/
    bin/studio.sh
```

the 'cd' command will route to the specific location.
then run the shell file (run.sh)  by:-

```
bash run.sh
```